# Android Webview LoadURL calling javascript with two Strings

Tags: java, javascript, android, webview

I am trying to call a javascript function from my webview while giving it two strings.
But one of the strings is always null. In my java code it isnt.

```
myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:Android.SelectTargetDirectory(\"" + fileName + "\", \"" + fileSizes + "\")");
```

That is what I am doing but with no success

Here the Javascript side:

```
selectTargetDirectory = function (fileName, fileSizes) {
     $.ajax({
         url: "/UploadFileProductsDialogController/ShowUploadDialog",
         data: { fileName: fileName, fileSizes: fileSizes },
         success: function (result) {
             Controller.ProcessResponse(result);
         },
         error: function (error, response) {
             alert(error);
         }
      );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try:

```
myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:SelectTargetDirectory('"
                            + fileName + "', '" + fileSizes + "')");
```

This is working in my case.

Comment: Please show your code. Are you sure you are passing correct value, and not a null variable? @zanzoken

Comment: yes in the debugger fileSizes has a value. I flipped them around and still the same problem. Now fileName does not get passed.